# Multiple outputs on a socket

Tags: java, sockets, arraylist

I'm trying to use a socket stream for multiple data transfers.

- for sending a `List<>`
- for sending text
- ...

Can I use just one socket for sending a `String` that tells the client what kind of data to expect, followed by the the expected data (in this case a `List<>`)?

Here's what I was thinking of:

```
//declarations
//outputs and inputs
    private ObjectInputStream input;
    private ObjectOutputStream output;
    private OutputStream checkStatus;
    private PrintWriter out;
    ...
    private void forwardMessage(List<User> clients) throws IOException {
        checkStatus = client.getOutputStream();
        out = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(checkStatus), true);
        out.println("Command Option 1");    
        client.shutdownOutput();
        output = new ObjectOutputStream (client.getOutputStream());
        for (int i = 0; i < clients.size(); i++) {      
            output.flush();
            output.writeObject(clients.get(i));
            output.flush();
            output.reset();
        }
        output.writeObject(null);
        client.shutdownOutput();
    }
```

The error given when I try this is "`java.net.SocketException: Socket is closed`"

I also tried to close the OutputStream but that gives the same result.

How can I use just one stream-socket for multiple data transfers?

Comment: why client.shutdownOutput(); before getOutputStream()?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to send this data over a network, this might help:

http://systembash.com/content/a-simple-java-udp-server-and-udp-client/

then when it comes to detecting the data you could always do something like this:

`if(name_of_your_string.compare("what_you_are_looking_for")){
        //what you want to do with "what_you_are_looking_for"
    }`